# Update Property Page or Tab Control Layout

Tags: mfc, cpropertysheet

After changing the text in a tab control's tab header, how do I tell it to recalculate the layout of the children (e.g., if the new tabs take up two rows)?

I am changing the tab text like this, from within a property page:

```
TC_ITEM ti;
ti.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
ti.pszText = _T("whatever....");
CTabCtrl *pTabs = ((CPropertySheetEx *)GetParent())->GetTabControl();
pTabs->SetItem(m_nIdx, &ti);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the MFC source code (dlgprop.cpp, in VC++ 6.0) and specifically the:

```
BOOL CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
```

It seems that the calculations that you need are done there.
Just try to call the `OnInitDialog()`. It does only property sheet window resizes.
Of course, you can check the source code for more *hints*.

Comment: This would have worked, but I chose to just EnableStackedTabs(FALSE) rather than introduce this complexity into my program.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted stacked rows but you had a problem with their appearance :)

Comment: Of course, you could have post your solution as an answer. Anyway, cheers.